# Dependecy Injection failing to resolve

Tags: asp.net, .net, dependency-injection

I have PaymentComponent class with deps

```
public PaymentComponent(
    ILogger<PaymentComponent> logger,
    IPolisaPremijaNacinSredstvaPlacanjaUseCase polisaPremijaNacinSredstvaUseCase,
    IPolisaInstrumentPlacanjaUseCase polisaInstrumentPlacanjaUseCase,
    IPolisaInstrumentPlacanjaPojedinacnoUseCase polisaInstrumentPlacanjaPojedinacnoUseCase,
    IUpitnikNacinPlacanjaUseCase upitnikNacinPlacanjaUseCase,
    IValidatePaymentDto validate)
{
    _logger = logger;
    _polisaPremijaNacinSredstvaUseCase = polisaPremijaNacinSredstvaUseCase;
    _polisaInstrumentPlacanjaUseCase = polisaInstrumentPlacanjaUseCase;
    _polisaInstrumentPlacanjaPojedinacnoUseCase = polisaInstrumentPlacanjaPojedinacnoUseCase;
    _upitnikNacinPlacanjaUseCase = upitnikNacinPlacanjaUseCase;
    _validate = validate;
}
```

class with dependecies for DI

```
public static class PaymentComponentDependencies
{
    public static void AddDependecies(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.TryAddScoped<IPolisaPremijaNacinSredstvaRepository, PolisaPremijaNacinSredstvaRepository>();
        services.TryAddScoped<IPolisaInstrumentPlacanjaRepository, PolisaInstrumentPlacanjaRepository>();
        services.TryAddScoped<IPolisaInstrumentPlacanjaPojedinacnoRepository, PolisaInstrumentPlacanjaPojedinacnoRepository>();
        services.TryAddScoped<IRepository<Klasifikacija>, ClassificationRepositoryCache>();
        services.TryAddScoped<IRepository<NacinPlacanja>, Repository<NacinPlacanja>>();
        services.TryAddScoped<IRepository<PoslovniPartner>, Repository<PoslovniPartner>>();
        services.TryAddScoped<IRepository<Valutum>, Repository<Valutum>>();
        services.TryAddScoped<IUpitnikNacinPlacanjaRepository, UpitnikNacinPlacanjaRepository>();
        services.TryAddScoped<IPolisaInstrumentPlacanjaPojedinacnoUseCase, PolisaInstrumentPlacanjaPojedinacnoUseCase>();
        services.TryAddScoped<IPolisaPremijaNacinSredstvaPlacanjaUseCase, PolisaPremijaNacinSredstvaPlacanjaUseCase>();
        services.TryAddScoped<IPolisaInstrumentPlacanjaUseCase, PolisaInstrumentPlacanjaUseCase>();
        services.TryAddScoped<IUpitnikNacinPlacanjaUseCase, UpitnikNacinPlacanjaUseCase>();
        services.TryAddScoped<IValidatePaymentDto, ValidatePaymentDto>();
    }
}
```

PaymentComponent project

[image: project structure]

When classes in project "PaymentHelper" are in "PaymentComponent" project, DI doesn't work. Error is that PaymentComponent can't be resolved because one of these classes. When I move from PaymentComponent project and create "PaymentHelper" like in picture, it works. I just moved classes in new project.

And every another project in sln is behaving like this, not just this project.

I use .net 6 web api project.

**UPDATE**

```
System.AggregateException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: ASP.Common.IComponent Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: ASP.Components.Policy.Payment.PaymentComponent': Unable to resolve service for type 'ASP.Components.Policy.Payment.PolisaPremijaNacinSredstvaPlacanja.IPolisaPremijaNacinSredstvaPlacanjaUseCase' while attempting to activate 'ASP.Components.Policy.Payment.PaymentComponent'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: ASP.Common.IComponentsOrchestrator Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: ASP.Common.ComponentsOrchestrator': Unable to resolve service for type 'ASP.Components.Policy.Payment.PolisaPremijaNacinSredstvaPlacanja.IPolisaPremijaNacinSredstvaPlacanjaUseCase' while attempting to activate 'ASP.Components.Policy.Payment.PaymentComponent'.)
  Source=Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection
  StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider..ctor(ICollection`1 serviceDescriptors, ServiceProviderOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollectionContainerBuilderExtensions.BuildServiceProvider(IServiceCollection services, ServiceProviderOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.DefaultServiceProviderFactory.CreateServiceProvider(IServiceCollection containerBuilder)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.ServiceFactoryAdapter`1.CreateServiceProvider(Object containerBuilder)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.CreateServiceProvider()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.Build()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.WebApplicationBuilder.Build()
   at Program.<Main>$(String[] args) in D:\GIT\Ins2\Main\V4\ASP.Ins.v4\src\PolicyAPI\Program.cs:line 57

  This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    [External Code]

Inner Exception 1:
InvalidOperationException: Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: ASP.Common.IComponent Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: ASP.Components.Policy.Payment.PaymentComponent': Unable to resolve service for type 'ASP.Components.Policy.Payment.PolisaPremijaNacinSredstvaPlacanja.IPolisaPremijaNacinSredstvaPlacanjaUseCase' while attempting to activate 'ASP.Components.Policy.Payment.PaymentComponent'.

Inner Exception 2:
InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'ASP.Components.Policy.Payment.PolisaPremijaNacinSredstvaPlacanja.IPolisaPremijaNacinSredstvaPlacanjaUseCase' while attempting to activate 'ASP.Components.Policy.Payment.PaymentComponent'.
```

**UPDATE**

Here is working example

Project Common

```
namespace Common
{
    public interface IComponent
    {
        public void Handle();
    }

    public class Component : IComponent
    {
        public void Handle() { 
        }
    }

}
```

Project Components.FirstComponent

```
using Common;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Extensions;

namespace Components.FirstComponent
{
    public class FirstCompoenent : IComponent
    {
        private readonly IFirstComponentDependency first;

        public FirstCompoenent(IFirstComponentDependency first)
        {
            this.first = first;
        }

        public void Handle()
        {
            first.Execute();
        }

        public static void AddDependecies(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.TryAddScoped<IFirstComponentDependency, FirstComponentDependecy>();
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
namespace Components.FirstComponent
{
    public class FirstComponentDependecy : IFirstComponentDependency
    {
        public void Execute()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public interface IFirstComponentDependency
    {
        public void Execute();
    }
}
```

ASP.NET web project

```
using Common;
using PolicyAPI.Helpers;

namespace DependecyInjection
{
    public static partial class StartupApiExtensions
    {
        public static void ScanForComponents(this IServiceCollection services)
        {
            var assemblies = AssemblyHelper.GetAssemblies("Components");

            foreach (var assembly in assemblies)
            {
                var types = assembly.GetExportedTypes().Where(t => t.IsClass && t.GetInterface(nameof(IComponent)) == typeof(IComponent)).ToList();
                foreach (var type in types)
                {
                    services.AddScoped(typeof(IComponent), type);
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

---

```
using System.Reflection;

namespace PolicyAPI.Helpers
{
    public class AssemblyHelper
    {
        public static List<Assembly> GetAssemblies(string startWith)
        {
            var returnAssemblies = new List<Assembly>();
            var dlls = Directory.GetFiles(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()!.Location)!, $"{startWith}*.dll");
            returnAssemblies.AddRange(dlls.Select(a => Assembly.LoadFile(a)));
            return returnAssemblies;
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
using Common;
using Components.FirstComponent;
using DependecyInjection;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

FirstCompoenent.AddDependecies(builder.Services);

//THIS WORKS
//builder.Services.AddScoped(typeof(IComponent), typeof(FirstCompoenent));

//THIS WORK ONLY IF DEPENDECIES ARE IN SEPARATE PROJECT
builder.Services.ScanForComponents();

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

---

[Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXMLW.png)

Comment: Would you mind updating your question so that it contains a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Such example should contain [no images of code](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) , but only actual code itself. It should also contain the full error details (exception message and full stack trace) *as text*.

Comment: Post the code and actual, complete error message as *text*. Images can't be googled, copied, compiled or tested. Descriptions of error messages aren't useful either. Post the actual, full exception text (not just the Exception.Message property). one of these classes.` isn't helpful. The exception contains the actual classes that caused the error

Comment: I don't know if I could reproduce it, I don't know what causing it. It's big project, I can't copy all code

Comment: I just moved classes from PaymentHelper project to PaymentComponent and this exception is thrown. I don't know what to look for.